# Is there a bug in Event Float in Logic Pro X?

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro

I have an Event List and Event Float open while working on my MIDI part. Here is what I have in Event List and how my first 1/4 of the bar look like:
[image]

So all thing looks nice, but here is what I'm getting in Event Float:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm doing it for the first time, so maybe I don't understand something here, or my setup is wrong, I don't know, but isnt Event Float meant to show matching event from Event List?